# (-) Symbol Used in Convert Method

Tags: c#

I was going through some C# code and came upon this line:

```
Matrix[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(grab[i, j] - '0');
```

What exactly does the ( - ) do??

What would be another way to write this if there is one?

Comment: `-` is the subtraction operator.  Here, it subtracts the value of `'0'`, which is 48 (the unicode point for the zero character).

Comment: What is the returning type of `grab[i, j]`?

Comment: char is the return type of grab

Comment: This is a poor man's char to int conversion for digits '0'-'9'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-` (minus) does exactly what it always does - subtracting. What happens here is subtracting the character code of zero `'0'` from the character at `[i,j]`. This converts a digit character to an integer value of the corresponding digit. For example, if you calculate

```
char digitChar = '7';
int digitVal = digitChar - '0';
```

the value of `digitVal` is seven.

Comment: Gotcha ok. I didn't think it was that simple and thought it might be something special to the Convert method. Thanks!